# rand validity measurement in R studio

Tags: data-mining

This is code for Rand index in RStudio "extCriteria(part1, part2, crit)".Here part1 and part2 are the partition vectors. I need to find the rand index value for this variable x<-c(total_data$`Average Price`).this x variable has 3720 elements.
Here my doubt is how to take part1,part2 partitions from this x variable? Here I have made three clusters from x using kmeans (k=3). Now is this possible to find Rand index value for x?

Answer (score 0):

The Rand index is defined on two sets of class labels.

It is not defined on a single variable, and not on numeric values like price.

So you must be looking for something else...

Comment: Here I made 3 clusters from x using Kmeans (k=3). I have 3 set of class labels.

Comment: Then you can use the function. You need two columns. One with the cluster assignment of each point, one with the class label of each.

Comment: I have two columns. Then what is function i have to use here?

Comment: Extcriteria maybe? I don't use R. I hate it's syntax.